# I can't get the expected output while it was just working fine

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
driver.get(f'https://beta.sam.gov/search?keywords=&sort=-modifiedDate&index=opp&is_active=true&page={currentpage}')
source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
outerDivs = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"tabindex": "-1" , "class": "ng-tns-c1-1 ng-star-inserted"})
```

> I just want to get all the divs having attrs={"tabindex": "-1" , "class": "ng-tns-c1-1 ng-star-inserted"}  from the given link https://beta.sam.gov/search?keywords=&sort=-modifiedDate&index=opp&is_active=true&page=1

In fact, it was working fine, but don't know why it is not working now, how to locate those elements. you may see the picture for more info.

[image]

Comment: Is the driver giving you the right source material? You might want to check if it suddenly stopped working.

Comment: how can I check what you suggested me?

Comment: Some sites block users from sending too many requests.If it was me I'd just print the source and ctrl+f to look for the contents.

Comment: it might be the issue because I am getting this line in my console  as well;[1005/142016.623:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Blocked by client", source: https://beta.sam.gov/token-assets/8e3b439bc40554e4bcb656864e9a1324/main.js (1)

Answer (score 0):

It might be synchronization issue.you need to provide some **explict** wait [**WebDriverWait**] to load the data on the page and then identify the element.

```
driver.get('https://beta.sam.gov/search?keywords=&sort=-modifiedDate&index=opp&is_active=true&page=1')
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div#search-results")))
source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
outerDivs = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"tabindex": "-1" , "class": "ng-tns-c1-1 ng-star-inserted"})
print(outerDivs)
```

You need to import below libarries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Data on console.

```
[<div class="ng-tns-c1-1 ng-star-inserted" tabindex="-1"><!-- --><opportunities-result class="usa-grid-full ng-tns-c1-1 ng-star-inserted"><div class="sam-ui grid"><div class="row"><div class="eight wide column"><h3 class="opportunity-title"><a class="wordbreak" href="/opp/43a0668f7c3e4a139964bdd29f4761fb/view?keywords=&amp;sort=-modifiedDate&amp;index=opp&amp;is_active=true&amp;page=1"> Solicitation for Sewer Maintenance Services - U.S. Embassy Belgrade, Serbia </a></h3><!-- --><p class="break-word ng-star-inserted"><span><p>fixed-priced and competitive</p>
</span>... </p><ul class="sam-ui small list"><!-- --><li class="ng-star-inserted"><strong>Awardee</strong><span class="sam-ui-br">DOO BEOTOK PANCEVO <!-- --><span class="ng-star-inserted">(565543126)</span></span></li><!-- --><li class="ng-star-inserted"><strong>Department/Ind. Agency</strong><!-- --><a class="sam-ui-br ng-star-inserted" href="/organization/100012062?keywords=&amp;sort=-modifiedDate&amp;index=opp&amp;is_active=true&amp;page=1"> STATE, DEPARTMENT OF </a><!-- --><!-- --></li><!-- --><li class="ng-star-inserted"><strong>Sub-tier</strong><!-- --><a class="sam-ui-br ng-star-inserted" href="/organization/300000190?keywords=&amp;sort=-modifiedDate&amp;index=opp&amp;is_active=true&amp;page=1"> STATE, DEPARTMENT OF </a><!-- --><!-- --></li><!-- --><li class="ng-star-inserted"><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><strong class="ng-star-inserted">Office</strong><span class="sam-ui-br">U.S.  EMBASSY BELGRADE</span></li></ul></div><div class="four wide column"><ul class="sam-ui small list"><!-- --><!-- --><li class="item"><span class="sam-ui mini label"> Contract Opportunities </span></li><li class="item"><strong>Notice ID</strong><span class="sam-ui-br wordbreak">19RB1020Q0012</span></li><!-- --><!-- --><li class="item last-modified-date ng-star-inserted"><strong>Last Updated Date</strong><span class="sam-ui-br"> Oct 5, 2020 <!-- --></span></li><!-- --><li class="item last-published-date ng-star-inserted"><strong>Last Published Date</strong><span class="sam-ui-br">Oct 5, 2020</span></li><li class="item opportunity-type"><strong>Type</strong><!-- --><!-- --><span class="sam-ui-br ng-star-inserted">Original Award Notice</span><!-- --></li></ul></div></div></div></opportunities-result><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><div class="sam-ui section divider"></div></div>, <div class="ng-tns-c1-1 ng-star-inserted" tabindex="-1"><!-- --><opportunities-result class="usa-grid-full ng-tns-c1-1 ng-star-inserted"><div class="sam-ui grid"><div class="row"><div class="eight wide column"><h3 class="opportunity-title"><a class="wordbreak" href="/opp/201c7b2f68294d69b85e892dd9d06ab2/view?keywords=&amp;sort=-modifiedDate&amp;index=opp&amp;is_active=true&amp;page=1"> Solicitation for Janitorial Services at U.S. Embassy Belgrade, Serbia </a></h3><!-- --><p class="break-word ng-star-inserted"><span><p>fixed-priced and competitive</p>
</span>... </p><ul class="sam-ui small list"><!-- --><li class="ng-star-inserted"><strong>Awardee</strong><span class="sam-ui-br">GRADJEVINAR GLU D.O.O. <!-- --><span class="ng-star-inserted">(506165536)</span></span></li><!-- --><li class="ng-star-inserted"><strong>Department/Ind. Agency</strong><!-- --><a class="sam-ui-br ng-star-inserted" href="/organization/100012062?keywords=&amp;sort=-modifiedDate&amp;index=opp&amp;is_active=true&amp;page=1"> STATE, DEPARTMENT OF </a><!-- --><!-- --></li><!-- --><li class="ng-star-inserted"><strong>Sub-tier</strong><!-- --><a class="sam-ui-br ng-star-inserted" href="/organization/300000190?keywords=&amp;sort=-modifiedDate&amp;index=opp&amp;is_active=true&amp;page=1"> STATE, DEPARTMENT OF </a><!-- --><!-- --></li><!-- --><li class="ng-star-inserted"><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><strong class="ng-star-inserted">Office</strong><span class="sam-ui-br">U.S.  EMBASSY BELGRADE</span></li></ul></div><div class="four wide column"><ul class="sam-ui small list"><!-- --><!-- --><li class="item"><span class="sam-ui mini label"> Contract Opportunities </span></li><li class="item"><strong>Notice ID</strong><span class="sam-ui-br wordbreak">19RB1020Q0013</span></li><!-- --><!-- --><li class="item last-modified-date ng-star-inserted"><strong>Last Updated Date</strong><span class="sam-ui-br"> Oct 5, 2020 <!-- --></span></li><!-- --><li class="item last-published-date ng-star-inserted"><strong>Last Published Date</strong><span class="sam-ui-br">Oct 5, 2020</span></li><li class="item opportunity-type"><strong>Type</strong><!-- --><!-- --><span class="sam-ui-br ng-star-inserted">Original Award Notice</span><!-- --></li></ul></div></div></div></opportunities-result><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><div class="sam-ui section divider"></div></div>, <div class="ng-tns-c1-1 ng-star-inserted" tabindex="-1"><!-- --><opportunities-result class="usa-grid-full ng-tns-c1-1 ng-star-inserted"><div class="sam-ui grid"><div class="row"><div class="eight wide column"><h3 class="opportunity-title"><a class="wordbreak" href="/opp/39bb3c378b294bb29c5952de6555a9a1/view?keywords=&amp;sort=-modifiedDate&amp;index=opp&amp;is_active=true&amp;page=1"> MANIFOLD-CLG </a></h3><!-- --><p class="break-word ng-star-inserted"><span>ITEM UNIQUE IDENTIFICATION AND VALUATION (MAR 2016)|19||||||||||||||||||||
HIGHER-LEVEL CONTRACT QUALITY REQUIREMENT|8|||||||||
WIDE AREA WORKFLOW PAY</span>... </p><ul class="sam-ui small list"><!-- --><!-- --><li class="ng-star-inserted"><strong>Department/Ind. Agency</strong><!-- --><a class="sam-ui-br ng-star-inserted" href="/organization/100000000?keywords=&amp;sort=-modifiedDate&amp;index=opp&amp;is_active=true&amp;page=1"> DEPT OF DEFENSE </a><!-- --><!-- --></li><!-- --><li class="ng-star-inserted"><strong>Sub-tier</strong><!-- --><a class="sam-ui-br ng-star-inserted" href="/organization/300000415?keywords=&amp;sort=-modifiedDate&amp;index=opp&amp;is_active=true&amp;page=1"> DEFENSE LOGISTICS AGENCY (DLA) </a><!-- --><!-- --></li><!-- --><li class="ng-star-inserted"><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><strong class="ng-star-inserted">Office</strong><span class="sam-ui-br">DLA AVIATION AT PHILADELPHIA, PA</span></li></ul></div><div class="four wide column"><ul class="sam-ui small list"><!-- --><!-- --><li class="item"><span class="sam-ui mini label"> Contract Opportunities </span></li><li class="item"><strong>Notice ID</strong><span class="sam-ui-br wordbreak">SPRPA120QX165</span></li><!-- --><li class="item current-response-date ng-star-inserted"><!-- --><!-- --><strong class="ng-star-inserted">Current Date Offers Due</strong><!-- --><span class="sam-ui-br">Oct 05, 2020</span></li><!-- --><li class="item last-modified-date ng-star-inserted"><strong>Last Updated Date</strong><span class="sam-ui-br"> Oct 5, 2020 <!-- --><a class="ng-star-inserted" href="/opp/39bb3c378b294bb29c5952de6555a9a1/view?keywords=&amp;sort=-modifiedDate&amp;index=opp&amp;is_active=true&amp;page=1#opportunity-history">(2)</a></span></li><!-- --><li class="item last-published-date ng-star-inserted"><strong>Last Published Date</strong><span class="sam-ui-br">Oct 5, 2020</span></li><li class="item opportunity-type"><strong>Type</strong><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><span class="sam-ui-br ng-star-inserted">Updated  Solicitation</span></li></ul></div></div></div></opportunities-result><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><div class="sam-ui section divider"></div></div>, <div class="ng-tns-c1-1 ng-star-inserted" tabindex="-1"><!-- --><opportunities-result class="usa-grid-full ng-tns-c1-1 ng-star-inserted"><div class="sam-ui grid"><div class="row"><div class="eight wide column"><h3 class="opportunity-title"><a class="wordbreak" href="/opp/47091d10ec7b4f0792a9349baa1cd178/view?keywords=&amp;sort=-modifiedDate&amp;index=opp&amp;is_active=true&amp;page=1"> 59--ANTENNA - AND OTHER REPLACEMENT PARTS </a></h3><!-- --><p class="break-word ng-star-inserted"><span>ITEM UNIQUE IDENTIFICATION AND VALUATION (MAR 2016)|19| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
TIME OF DELIVERY (JUNE 1997)|20| | | | | | | | | | | | |</span>... </p><ul class="sam-ui small list"><!-- --><!-- --><li class="ng-star-inserted"><strong>Department/Ind. Agency</strong><!-- --><a class="sam-ui-br ng-star-inserted" href="/organization/100000000?keywords=&amp;sort=-modifiedDate&amp;index=opp&amp;is_active=true&amp;page=1"> DEPT OF DEFENSE </a><!-- --><!-- --></li><!-- --><li class="ng-star-inserted"><strong>Sub-tier</strong><!-- --><a class="sam-ui-br ng-star-inserted" href="/organization/300000188?keywords=&amp;sort=-modifiedDate&amp;index=opp&amp;is_active=true&amp;page=1"> DEPT OF THE NAVY </a><!-- --><!-- --></li><!-- --><li class="ng-star-inserted"><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><strong class="ng-star-inserted">Office</strong><span class="sam-ui-br">NAVSUP WEAPON SYSTEMS SUPPORT</span></li></ul></div><div class="four wide column"><ul class="sam-ui small list"><!-- --><!-- --><li class="item"><span class="sam-ui mini label"> Contract Opportunities </span></li><li class="item"><strong>Notice ID</strong><span class="sam-ui-br wordbreak">N0038320RH495</span></li><!-- --><li class="item current-response-date ng-star-inserted"><!-- --><!-- --><strong class="ng-star-inserted">Current Date Offers Due</strong><!-- --><span class="sam-ui-br">Nov 02, 2020</span></li><!-- --><li class="item last-modified-date ng-star-inserted"><strong>Last Updated Date</strong><span class="sam-ui-br"> Oct 5, 2020 <!-- --></span></li><!-- --><li class="item last-published-date ng-star-inserted"><strong>Last Published Date</strong><span class="sam-ui-br">Oct 5, 2020</span></li><li class="item opportunity-type"><strong>Type</strong><!-- --><!-- --><span class="sam-ui-br ng-star-inserted">Original Solicitation</span><!-- --></li></ul></div></div></div></opportunities-result><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><div class="sam-ui section divider"></div></div>, <div class="ng-tns-c1-1 ng-star-inserted" tabindex="-1"><!-- --><opportunities-result class="usa-grid-full ng-tns-c1-1 ng-star-inserted"><div class="sam-ui grid"><div class="row"><div class="eight wide column"><h3 class="opportunity-title"><a class="wordbreak" href="/opp/acfaa1eff39f4ce09117f263de8a346f/view?keywords=&amp;sort=-modifiedDate&amp;index=opp&amp;is_active=true&amp;page=1"> 16--ADAPTER,PROPELLER </a></h3><!-- --><p class="break-word ng-star-inserted"><span>CONTACT INFORMATION|4|APAC.27|R4Y|2157378264|VINCENT.AMBROSINI@DLA.MIL|
ITEM UNIQUE IDENTIFICATION AND VALUATION (MAR 2016)|19||||||||||||||||||||
WID</span>... </p><ul class="sam-ui small list"><!-- --><!-- --><li class="ng-star-inserted"><strong>Department/Ind. Agency</strong><!-- --><a class="sam-ui-br ng-star-inserted" href="/organization/100000000?keywords=&amp;sort=-modifiedDate&amp;index=opp&amp;is_active=true&amp;page=1"> DEPT OF DEFENSE </a><!-- --><!-- --></li><!-- --><li class="ng-star-inserted"><strong>Sub-tier</strong><!-- --><a class="sam-ui-br ng-star-inserted" href="/organization/300000415?keywords=&amp;sort=-modifiedDate&amp;index=opp&amp;is_active=true&amp;page=1"> DEFENSE LOGISTICS AGENCY (DLA) </a><!-- --><!-- --></li><!-- --><li class="ng-star-inserted"><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><strong class="ng-star-inserted">Office</strong><span class="sam-ui-br">DLA AVIATION AT PHILADELPHIA, PA</span></li></ul></div><div class="four wide column"><ul class="sam-ui small list"><!-- --><!-- --><li class="item"><span class="sam-ui mini label"> Contract Opportunities </span></li><li class="item"><strong>Notice ID</strong><span class="sam-ui-br wordbreak">SPRPA120QW452</span></li><!-- --><li class="item current-response-date ng-star-inserted"><!-- --><!-- --><strong class="ng-star-inserted">Current Date Offers Due</strong><!-- --><span class="sam-ui-br">Nov 02, 2020</span></li><!-- --><li class="item last-modified-date ng-star-inserted"><strong>Last Updated Date</strong><span class="sam-ui-br"> Oct 5, 2020 <!-- --></span></li><!-- --><li class="item last-published-date ng-star-inserted"><strong>Last Published Date</strong><span class="sam-ui-br">Oct 5, 2020</span></li><li class="item opportunity-type"><strong>Type</strong><!-- --><!-- --><span class="sam-ui-br ng-star-inserted">Original Solicitation</span><!-- --></li></ul></div></div></div></opportunities-result><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><div class="sam-ui section divider"></div></div>, <div class="ng-tns-c1-1 ng-star-inserted" tabindex="-1"><!-- --><opportunities-result class="usa-grid-full ng-tns-c1-1 ng-star-inserted"><div class="sam-ui grid"><div class="row"><div class="eight wide column"><h3 class="opportunity-title"><a class="wordbreak" href="/opp/aff77daf0cf546e390e272b21b04dd6e/view?keywords=&amp;sort=-modifiedDate&amp;index=opp&amp;is_active=true&amp;page=1"> 16--BACK PANEL AS,MPCD, </a></h3><!-- --><p class="break-word ng-star-inserted"><span>CONTACT INFORMATION|4|N731.33|F/18|N/a|Matthew.Pizzarelli@Navy.mil|
ITEM UNIQUE IDENTIFICATION AND VALUATION (MAR 2016)|19||||||||||||||||||||
HIGHER-</span>... </p><ul class="sam-ui small list"><!-- --><!-- --><li class="ng-star-inserted"><strong>Department/Ind. Agency</strong><!-- --><a class="sam-ui-br ng-star-inserted" href="/organization/100000000?keywords=&amp;sort=-modifiedDate&amp;index=opp&amp;is_active=true&amp;page=1"> DEPT OF DEFENSE </a><!-- --><!-- --></li><!-- --><li class="ng-star-inserted"><strong>Sub-tier</strong><!-- --><a class="sam-ui-br ng-star-inserted" href="/organization/300000188?keywords=&amp;sort=-modifiedDate&amp;index=opp&amp;is_active=true&amp;page=1"> DEPT OF THE NAVY </a><!-- --><!-- --></li><!-- --><li class="ng-star-inserted"><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><strong class="ng-star-inserted">Office</strong><span class="sam-ui-br">NAVSUP WEAPON SYSTEMS SUPPORT</span></li></ul></div><div class="four wide column"><ul class="sam-ui small list"><!-- --><!-- --><li class="item"><span class="sam-ui mini label"> Contract Opportunities </span></li><li class="item"><strong>Notice ID</strong><span class="sam-ui-br wordbreak">N0038320QN548</span></li><!-- --><li class="item current-response-date ng-star-inserted"><!-- --><!-- --><strong class="ng-star-inserted">Current Date Offers Due</strong><!-- --><span class="sam-ui-br">Nov 02, 2020</span></li><!-- --><li class="item last-modified-date ng-star-inserted"><strong>Last Updated Date</strong><span class="sam-ui-br"> Oct 5, 2020 <!-- --></span></li><!-- --><li class="item last-published-date ng-star-inserted"><strong>Last Published Date</strong><span class="sam-ui-br">Oct 5, 2020</span></li><li class="item opportunity-type"><strong>Type</strong><!-- --><!-- --><span class="sam-ui-br ng-star-inserted">Original Solicitation</span><!-- --></li></ul></div></div></div></opportunities-result><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><div class="sam-ui section divider"></div></div>, <div class="ng-tns-c1-1 ng-star-inserted" tabindex="-1"><!-- --><opportunities-result class="usa-grid-full ng-tns-c1-1 ng-star-inserted"><div class="sam-ui grid"><div class="row"><div class="eight wide column"><h3 class="opportunity-title"><a class="wordbreak" href="/opp/3b8fc586a9834c9587b4af5198000497/view?keywords=&amp;sort=-modifiedDate&amp;index=opp&amp;is_active=true&amp;page=1"> Grounds keeping services at the new embassy compound in Belgrade, Serbia </a></h3><!-- --><p class="break-word ng-star-inserted"><span><p>Contract was  fixed-price and competitive</p>
</span>... </p><ul class="sam-ui small list"><!-- --><li class="ng-star-inserted"><strong>Awardee</strong><span class="sam-ui-br">GRADJEVINAR GLU D.O.O. <!-- --><span class="ng-star-inserted">(506165536)</span></span></li><!-- --><li class="ng-star-inserted"><strong>Department/Ind. Agency</strong><!-- --><a class="sam-ui-br ng-star-inserted" href="/organization/100012062?keywords=&amp;sort=-modifiedDate&amp;index=opp&amp;is_active=true&amp;page=1"> STATE, DEPARTMENT OF </a><!-- --><!-- --></li><!-- --><li class="ng-star-inserted"><strong>Sub-tier</strong><!-- --><a class="sam-ui-br ng-star-inserted" href="/organization/300000190?keywords=&amp;sort=-modifiedDate&amp;index=opp&amp;is_active=true&amp;page=1"> STATE, DEPARTMENT OF </a><!-- --><!-- --></li><!-- --><li class="ng-star-inserted"><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><strong class="ng-star-inserted">Office</strong><span class="sam-ui-br">U.S.  EMBASSY BELGRADE</span></li></ul></div><div class="four wide column"><ul class="sam-ui small list"><!-- --><!-- --><li class="item"><span class="sam-ui mini label"> Contract Opportunities </span></li><li class="item"><strong>Notice ID</strong><span class="sam-ui-br wordbreak">19RB1020C0002</span></li><!-- --><!-- --><li class="item last-modified-date ng-star-inserted"><strong>Last Updated Date</strong><span class="sam-ui-br"> Oct 5, 2020 <!-- --></span></li><!-- --><li class="item last-published-date ng-star-inserted"><strong>Last Published Date</strong><span class="sam-ui-br">Oct 5, 2020</span></li><li class="item opportunity-type"><strong>Type</strong><!-- --><!-- --><span class="sam-ui-br ng-star-inserted">Original Award Notice</span><!-- --></li></ul></div></div></div></opportunities-result><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><div class="sam-ui section divider"></div></div>, <div class="ng-tns-c1-1 ng-star-inserted" tabindex="-1"><!-- --><opportunities-result class="usa-grid-full ng-tns-c1-1 ng-star-inserted"><div class="sam-ui grid"><div class="row"><div class="eight wide column"><h3 class="opportunity-title"><a class="wordbreak" href="/opp/8c1a6e100ea14abdb29808d920028e5d/view?keywords=&amp;sort=-modifiedDate&amp;index=opp&amp;is_active=true&amp;page=1"> Ali Al Salem, Kuwait Giant Voice Expansion </a></h3><!-- --><p class="break-word ng-star-inserted"><span><p>A sole source award for the expansion of the existing ATI integrated giant voice system on Ali Al Saleem Air Base, Kuwait. Market research indicate</p></span>... </p><ul class="sam-ui small list"><!-- --><li class="ng-star-inserted"><strong>Awardee</strong><span class="sam-ui-br">ACOUSTIC TECHNOLOGY, INC. <!-- --><span class="ng-star-inserted">(050695204)</span></span></li><!-- --><li class="ng-star-inserted"><strong>Department/Ind. Agency</strong><!-- --><a class="sam-ui-br ng-star-inserted" href="/organization/100000000?keywords=&amp;sort=-modifiedDate&amp;index=opp&amp;is_active=true&amp;page=1"> DEPT OF DEFENSE </a><!-- --><!-- --></li><!-- --><li class="ng-star-inserted"><strong>Sub-tier</strong><!-- --><a class="sam-ui-br ng-star-inserted" href="/organization/300000251?keywords=&amp;sort=-modifiedDate&amp;index=opp&amp;is_active=true&amp;page=1"> DEPT OF THE AIR FORCE </a><!-- --><!-- --></li><!-- --><li class="ng-star-inserted"><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><strong class="ng-star-inserted">Office</strong><span class="sam-ui-br">FA5703  386 ECONS LGC</span></li></ul></div><div class="four wide column"><ul class="sam-ui small list"><!-- --><!-- --><li class="item"><span class="sam-ui mini label"> Contract Opportunities </span></li><li class="item"><strong>Notice ID</strong><span class="sam-ui-br wordbreak">FA570320P0287</span></li><!-- --><!-- --><li class="item last-modified-date ng-star-inserted"><strong>Last Updated Date</strong><span class="sam-ui-br"> Oct 5, 2020 <!-- --></span></li><!-- --><li class="item last-published-date ng-star-inserted"><strong>Last Published Date</strong><span class="sam-ui-br">Oct 5, 2020</span></li><li class="item opportunity-type"><strong>Type</strong><!-- --><!-- --><span class="sam-ui-br ng-star-inserted">Original Award Notice</span><!-- --></li></ul></div></div></div></opportunities-result><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><div class="sam-ui section divider"></div></div>, <div class="ng-tns-c1-1 ng-star-inserted" tabindex="-1"><!-- --><opportunities-result class="usa-grid-full ng-tns-c1-1 ng-star-inserted"><div class="sam-ui grid"><div class="row"><div class="eight wide column"><h3 class="opportunity-title"><a class="wordbreak" href="/opp/d96854d260964925a73addab6476e004/view?keywords=&amp;sort=-modifiedDate&amp;index=opp&amp;is_active=true&amp;page=1"> Dewatering Pump restoration and maintenance service, Diesel Powered </a></h3><!-- --><p class="break-word ng-star-inserted"><span><p>SOURCES SOUGHT NOTICE. No solicitation is available. This notice is released pursuant to FAR 15.201(e) Exchange with Industry.</p>
<p>Portsmouth N</p></span>... </p><ul class="sam-ui small list"><!-- --><!-- --><li class="ng-star-inserted"><strong>Department/Ind. Agency</strong><!-- --><a class="sam-ui-br ng-star-inserted" href="/organization/100000000?keywords=&amp;sort=-modifiedDate&amp;index=opp&amp;is_active=true&amp;page=1"> DEPT OF DEFENSE </a><!-- --><!-- --></li><!-- --><li class="ng-star-inserted"><strong>Sub-tier</strong><!-- --><a class="sam-ui-br ng-star-inserted" href="/organization/300000188?keywords=&amp;sort=-modifiedDate&amp;index=opp&amp;is_active=true&amp;page=1"> DEPT OF THE NAVY </a><!-- --><!-- --></li><!-- --><li class="ng-star-inserted"><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><strong class="ng-star-inserted">Office</strong><span class="sam-ui-br">PORTSMOUTH NAVAL SHIPYARD GF</span></li></ul></div><div class="four wide column"><ul class="sam-ui small list"><!-- --><!-- --><li class="item"><span class="sam-ui mini label"> Contract Opportunities </span></li><li class="item"><strong>Notice ID</strong><span class="sam-ui-br wordbreak">N3904021QPUMP</span></li><!-- --><li class="item current-response-date ng-star-inserted"><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><strong class="ng-star-inserted">Current Response Date</strong><span class="sam-ui-br">Oct 06, 2020 10:00 am EDT</span></li><!-- --><li class="item last-modified-date ng-star-inserted"><strong>Last Updated Date</strong><span class="sam-ui-br"> Oct 5, 2020 <!-- --></span></li><!-- --><li class="item last-published-date ng-star-inserted"><strong>Last Published Date</strong><span class="sam-ui-br">Oct 5, 2020</span></li><li class="item opportunity-type"><strong>Type</strong><!-- --><!-- --><span class="sam-ui-br ng-star-inserted">Original Sources Sought</span><!-- --></li></ul></div></div></div></opportunities-result><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><div class="sam-ui section divider"></div></div>, <div class="ng-tns-c1-1 ng-star-inserted" tabindex="-1"><!-- --><opportunities-result class="usa-grid-full ng-tns-c1-1 ng-star-inserted"><div class="sam-ui grid"><div class="row"><div class="eight wide column"><h3 class="opportunity-title"><a class="wordbreak" href="/opp/a9bf3b7f6c0841fb8dd9e5aa7d19bbba/view?keywords=&amp;sort=-modifiedDate&amp;index=opp&amp;is_active=true&amp;page=1"> 84--HELMET,GROUND TROOP </a></h3><!-- --><p class="break-word ng-star-inserted"><span>Proposed procurement for NSN 8415016873713 HELMET,GROUND TROOP:
Line 0001 Qty 26     UI EA  Deliver To: ASSAULT CRAFT UNIT ACU 5 By: 0005 DAYS ADO
Lin</span>... </p><ul class="sam-ui small list"><!-- --><!-- --><li class="ng-star-inserted"><strong>Department/Ind. Agency</strong><!-- --><a class="sam-ui-br ng-star-inserted" href="/organization/100000000?keywords=&amp;sort=-modifiedDate&amp;index=opp&amp;is_active=true&amp;page=1"> DEPT OF DEFENSE </a><!-- --><!-- --></li><!-- --><li class="ng-star-inserted"><strong>Sub-tier</strong><!-- --><a class="sam-ui-br ng-star-inserted" href="/organization/300000415?keywords=&amp;sort=-modifiedDate&amp;index=opp&amp;is_active=true&amp;page=1"> DEFENSE LOGISTICS AGENCY (DLA) </a><!-- --><!-- --></li><!-- --><li class="ng-star-inserted"><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><strong class="ng-star-inserted">Office</strong><span class="sam-ui-br">DLA TROOP SUPPORT</span></li></ul></div><div class="four wide column"><ul class="sam-ui small list"><!-- --><!-- --><li class="item"><span class="sam-ui mini label"> Contract Opportunities </span></li><li class="item"><strong>Notice ID</strong><span class="sam-ui-br wordbreak">SPE1C121T0011</span></li><!-- --><li class="item current-response-date ng-star-inserted"><!-- --><!-- --><strong class="ng-star-inserted">Current Date Offers Due</strong><!-- --><span class="sam-ui-br">Oct 16, 2020</span></li><!-- --><li class="item last-modified-date ng-star-inserted"><strong>Last Updated Date</strong><span class="sam-ui-br"> Oct 5, 2020 <!-- --></span></li><!-- --><li class="item last-published-date ng-star-inserted"><strong>Last Published Date</strong><span class="sam-ui-br">Oct 5, 2020</span></li><li class="item opportunity-type"><strong>Type</strong><!-- --><!-- --><span class="sam-ui-br ng-star-inserted">Original Combined Synopsis/Solicitation</span><!-- --></li></ul></div></div></div></opportunities-result><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><!-- --><div class="sam-ui section divider"></div></div>]
```